# Input/output error while copying from hadoop file system to local

Tags: linux, hadoop, data-science, bigdata

hadoop fs -copyToLocal /paulp  /abcd (I want to copy the folder paulp in hadoop  file system to abcd folder in local)

But the oputput of that command shows like  this( copyToLocal: mkdir `/abcd': Input/output error)
I use ubuntu 14.04 and hadoop 2.7.1 ...

can you provide apt solution to this?